# Certificate found although deleted

Tags: c#, certificate, x509certificate

I imported a certificate called S0021679776.pfx to a Windows 8 through CERTMGR.MSC.
Then I deleted it (from the certificates manager as well as deleting the file itself).
However, when I run the following code, it still finds the certificate.
Why is that? I searched for certificate by "Issue By" and it is not found.

```
        static void FindCert(string CertificateName)
        {
            X509Certificate2Collection certificates;

            Console.WriteLine("looking for certificate " + CertificateName);
            X509Store store = new X509Store("My", StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            //FindBySubjectDistinguishedName
            certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, CertificateName, false);
            Console.WriteLine("# of certificates: " + certificates.Count.ToString());

            foreach (X509Certificate2 item in certificates)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.GetName());
            }


        }
}
```

The output:

looking for certificate S0021679776

# of certificates: 1

C=DE, O=SAP Trust Community, OU=SAP Service Marketplace, CN=S0021679776

Comment: Certificates is a Dictionary.  So you remove the value of the dictionary without removing the Key.

Comment: I don't understand. I deleted the certificate through CERTMGR. The same place where I added it. It is not showing there anymore. So why is the call to store.Certificates.Find() find it?
How should I delete a certificate so it is not found anymore?

Comment: You just remove the certificate.  Didn't remove from store.Certificates